# Zend Studio 7 code folding

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, zend-studio, code-folding

just another simple question (as always). 
I have tried to find out how to fold a PHP function using shortcut in Zend Studio 7 and have found on the Preferences section that the shortcut is Ctrl+Numpad_Add.

I tried it and also changed into new binding key, but it is still not working.
Any idea how to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very small "-" icon next to the line number...just in case you're still searching for the shortcut key